# angular: http request in service, return data to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new to the whole angular thing and I'm having a little problem.

What I want to do is have a service that communicates with an API, the API response is saved in the service and so it's available to different controllers.

The service looks like this:

```
angular.module('exampleApp').service('locationService', function ($http) {

    this.tiles = {};
    var location = this;

    this.getLocationTiles = function() {
        return $http.get('http://some.url').then(function(data) {
            location.tiles = data.data;
        });
    }
});
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('exampleApp')
    .controller('TileCtrl', ['$scope', 'locationService', function ($scope, locationService) {
        $scope.tiles = locationService.tiles;
    }]);
```

Is there a more or less simple way to achieve that $scope.tiles actually gets the data when the http call was successfull?

Comment: You need to define a callback... So the scope could be updated when the background task has finished

Comment: I wouldn't recommend storing the state in a service like this - instead consider storing it in local storage or some other kind of web storage. Storing it in the service gives the service two reasons to change, which is a violation of SRP

Answer (score 0):

**Details of how http in angular**

so this is from a previous question I answered about Ionic but it applies here too. You can see how the http request is supposed to work starting with the factory and then the controller until finally you reach the html.

**Factory in services.js**

Start off with a factory but replace my url wit yours.

```
.factory('Friends', function ($http, $rootScope, $stateParams) {

  return {
    all: function () {
      return $http.get('https://friends.json/all', { params: { user_id: $rootScope.session } })
    },
    get: function () {
      return $http.get('https://friends.json/getOne', { params: { user_id: $rootScope.session, chat_id: $stateParams.idchat } })
    },
    add: function (id) {
      return $http.get('https://friends.json/new', { params: {idfriends:id}})
    }
  };
});
```

**Controller in controllers.js**

Then make a controller like this. This is when you instantiate the factory to get your data.

```
.controller('FirendsCtrl', function ($scope, Friends) {

  Friends.all().success(function (response) {
    $scope.chats = response;
  })
})
```

**Scope added to View**

This will bind the data to the scope. And there for make it available to the view.

Finally you will be able to bring the data to the view via $scope
I have created a list here of all the friends that you get from get friend with a nice side swip to add more or delete.

```
<ion-view view-title="Contacts">
  <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="data in friends">
          <h1>{{ data.username }}</h1>
          <p>{{ data.friendNumber}}</p>
          <i class="icon ion-chevron-left icon-accessory"></i>
          <ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="viewFriend(viewFriend(data.idfriends))">View Friend</ion-option-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="deleteFriend(remove(data.idfriends))">Delete</ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Disclaimer**

this is some code that I had previously written. I have not ran this version exactly but my full version works fine.

if you wish to see the full code please feel free to check out my github repo https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000

Answer (score 0):

You may wait for the promise to complete, then set the `$scope.tiles` property.

```
angular.module('exampleApp')
.controller('TileCtrl', ['$scope', 'locationService', function ($scope, locationService) {
    locationService.getLocationTiles().then(function() {
      $scope.tiles = locationService.tiles;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.